# Assistance with Rainfall Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have an assignment over methods that I am completely stuck on. I'm looking for general help if possible as I can't seem to understand this no matter how many times I rewatch the lesson. Thank you for your time reading and possibly helping me out! Below is the assignment and my code so far.

"Write a RainFall class that stores the total rainfall for each of 12 months into an array of doubles. The program should have methods that return the following:

- the total rainfall for the year
- the average monthly rainfall
- the month with the most rain
- the month with the least rain

```
public class RainfallClass
{
    //constant variable
    public final int NUM_MONTHS = 12;

    // array for amount each month
    private double[] averageAmnt = new double[NUM_MONTHS];

    public double getTotal(int i )
    {
        return averageAmnt[i] * 12;
    }

    public double getAvg(int i)
    {
        return averageAmnt[i];
    }

    public double getMost(int i)
    {
        return 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you intend `int i` to mean, with respect to the requirements?

Comment: You should have a way to set a month's rainfall, and another to get the rainfall for a month.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the prompt says you are to store *total rainfall* per month, not average.  Your array should be something like "monthlyTotal" or "monthlyRain", nothing about average.

As other commenters mentioned, the input you're taking in each of your methods doesn't really make sense.  Think, what do each of those methods need in order to do their job?  To find the sum of an array, all you need is that array (which the functions have access to as they're in the same class).

There really isn't very much to help you on with the rest, you haven't provided much to work with.  Below is my attempt at the problem, in the future please try to put in a bit more effort on your own before posting.

```
public class RainFall {


    double[] monthlyRain;

    public double getTotal() {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < monthlyRain.length; i++) {
            sum+=monthlyRain[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public double getAvg() {
        return getTotal()/12;
    }

    public int getMost(){
        int maxPos = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i < monthlyRain.length; i++) {
            if (monthlyRain[i] > monthlyRain[maxPos]) {
                maxPos = i;
            }
        }
        return maxPos;
    }

    public int getLeast(){
        int minPos = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i < monthlyRain.length; i++) {
            if (monthlyRain[i] < monthlyRain[minPos]) {
                minPos = i;
            }
        }
        return minPos;
    }
}
```

You will still need to provide some way to set the data in monthlyRain (a setter or constructor).

Hope this helps you understand what the prompt was looking for.  Let me know if you have any questions.